# Object size relation with depth map

Tags: image-processing, depth, color-depth

I have depth map of an image and i want to place new object to this image. In other words,i need to scale object by using depth map information before the placement. Can you recomment any project, paper, or idea related with these?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain more precisely what you mean by "scale object by using depth map?". Apart from being very vague, your question is also a bit off-topic for SO (Questions requesting projects, papers, etc). https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: sorry for missing details. Scale operation's purpose is to preserve object size relation with depth map. For example, i have sky image depth map, and i want to place plane to sky. I need to scale original plane images so that its sizes compatible with depth.